# What does "question eligible for bounty in 2 days" mean?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to know the meaning of this sentence below my question:

> question eligible for bounty in 2 days

Could you give me the right meaning of this sentence?

Comment: That is a very terse (headline-ese) version of "This question will be eligible to have a bounty posted on it in two days".  bounty = a reward of (extra) points to the person answering it.  The terse version is used because screen space is limited. The verb-to-be is dropped, as are other phrases which the reader is assumed to understand from context.

Comment: To those who would close: the question can be answered from a grammatical slant. It doesn't have to be relegated to Meta.

Comment: @TRomano It could be answered as a question about English, but if folks can't tell whether it is a question about how the site works or a question about the sentence itself, it should have more detail than it does. 박용현 has been a member here for almost four years and has received a lot of guidance recently on how to improve the quality of his questions. I am disappointed that guidance has been ignored.

Answer (score 7):

[Bounties](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on Stack Exchange are a way to attract more attention to a question (for whatever reason); you can think of them as advertisements paid for with your own reputation.

The help center also mentions the following, which explains your question:

> #### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

The idea behind this is that in the first two days, a question should generate enough attention on its own, merely by being new.